# Uploading an image from contact form and send as email attachement

Tags: php, image-uploading

I am trying to add a new field in the contact us form field, but I am stumped on how to properly do this.  I simply need to have the uploaded file be sent as an attachment of the contact us email. Thanks in advance Rahul

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$submitted = FALSE;
if ($_POST['contact_form']) {
$submitted = TRUE;  // The form has been submitted and everything is ok so far…
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES);
$country = htmlspecialchars($_POST['country'], ENT_QUOTES);
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES);
if ($name == "") {
// if the name is blank… give error notice.
echo "<p>Please enter your name.</p>";
$submitted = FALSE;  // Set this to FALSE so that it the message is not sent.
}
if ($email == "") {
// if the email is blank… give error notice.
echo "<p>Please enter your e-mail address so that we can reply to you.</p>";
$submitted = FALSE;  // Set this to FALSE so that it the message is not sent.
}
if ($country == "") {
// if the country is blank… give error notice.
echo "<p>Please enter your country.</p>";
$submitted = FALSE;  // Set this to FALSE so that it the message is not sent.
}
if ($message == "") {
// if the message is blank… give error notice.
echo "<p>Please enter a question.</p>";
$submitted = FALSE;  // Set this to FALSE so that it the message is not sent.
}
if ($_POST['email'] != "" && (!strstr($_POST['email'],"@") || !strstr($_POST['email'],".")))
{
// if the string does not contain "@" OR the string does not contain "." then…
// supply a different error notice.
echo "<p>Please enter a valid e-mail address.</p>";
$submitted = FALSE;  // Set this to FALSE so that it the message is not sent.
}

$problemIn = '';

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
              ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] 
               : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$to = "rahul@test.com";  // Set the target email address.
$header = "From: $email";
$attention = "Someone has sent you question from your webpage!";
$message = "Name: $name \n Country: $country \n Question: $message \n IP Address: $ip \n Link: $url \n";
if ($submitted == TRUE)
{
mail($to, $attention, $message, $header);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Thank you. Your question has been sent.");</script>';
}
}
?>
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <form method="post" name="frmmail" id="frmmail" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ?>" onSubmit="javascript: return validation();" eenctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="name" id="txtname" value="" placeholder="Name" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Name')" class="usericon" />
    <input name="email" id="txtmail" value="" placeholder="Email" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Email')" class="emailicon" />
    <input name="country" id="txtcountry" value="" placeholder="Country" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Country')" style="margin:0" class="countryicon" />
    <textarea name="message" id="txtmsg" placeholder="Your Comment/Question" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Your Question')" class="msgicon"></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="file" class="file" /> 
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
<input type="hidden" name="contact_form" value="submitted" />
    </form>
```

Comment: You need to capture the upload file using the [$_FILES](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#113161) for sending attachment using php mail

Answer (score 3):

Here is HTML Form

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Email Attachment Without Upload - Excellent Web World</title>
<style>
body{ font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;}
th{ background:#999999; text-align:right; vertical-align:top;}
input{ width:181px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="emailSend.php" method="post" name="mainform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
   <tr>
    <th>Your Name</th>
    <td><input name="fieldFormName" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
    <th>Your Email</th>
    <td><input name="fieldFormEmail" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>To Email</th>
    <td><input name="toEmail" type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <td><input name="fieldSubject" type="text" id="fieldSubject"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Comments</th>
    <td><textarea name="fieldDescription" cols="20" rows="4" id="fieldDescription"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Attach Your File</th>
  <td><input name="attachment" type="file"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php

$to = $_POST['toEmail'];
$fromEmail = $_POST['fieldFormEmail']; 
$fromName = $_POST['fieldFormName']; 
$subject = $_POST['fieldSubject']; 
$message = $_POST['fieldDescription'];

/* GET File Variables */ 
$tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; 
$fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type']; 
$fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name']; 

/* Start of headers */ 
$headers = "From: $fromName"; 

if (file($tmpName)) { 
  /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
  $file = fopen($tmpName,'rb'); 
  $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName)); 
  fclose($file); 

  /* a boundary string */
  $randomVal = md5(time()); 
  $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x"; 

  /* Header for File Attachment */
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
  $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\""; 

  /* Multipart Boundary above message */
  $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
  "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
  "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
  $message . "\n\n"; 

  /* Encoding file data */
  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

  /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
  $message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
  "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" . 
  " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" . 
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
  $data . "\n\n" . 
  "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n"; 
} 

$flgchk = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers"); 

if($flgchk){
  echo "A email has been sent to: $to";
 }
else{
  echo "Error in Email sending";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Its worked for me . I used this in Magento